# Add New Printer disabled - grayed out using Gnome Shell 

Tags: 11.10, gnome, printing

I'm running Gnome Shell in Ubuntu 11.10.

When I go to `Gnome Control Center` and click on printers, the `Add New Printer` button is grayed out (disabled).

When I logged into Unity, I added the network printer with no problem, and the printer remained when I logged back into Gnome Classic (Gnome Shell). However, I am not able to add any further printers; the `+` and `-` buttons are grayed out.

How do I fix this permanently?

Thanks!

Comment: I used both the unity gui and the CUPS (`http://localhost:631` in browser window) and I find that the CUPS method is WAY less painful and in MY case seemed to have better driver support.

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same issue here. One workaround is use cups to add printer, that works for me. http://localhost:631.

Just found another way, execute "system-config-printer" in terminal, it will open the printer config in Unity, and you can add/remove printers in gnome. By default in gnome it opens a different printer application which you can't add printer.